# Creating a 3D Array using For loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I need to create a 5 by 4 by 3 array. It will initialize the ordered triple at each row and column to [1,2,3].
Output it in this format.

[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]

[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]

[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]

[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]

[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]

I am using Eclipse Oxygen to do this. Below is what I have done so far.

public class Triples {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] scores = new int[5][4][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < scores[i].length; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < scores[i][a].length; b++) {
                scores[i][a][b] = i*1;

            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < scores[i].length; a++)
        {
            System.out.print("{");
            for (int b = 0; b < scores[i][a].length; b++)
            {
                System.out.print(scores[i][a][b] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("} ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

The issue is that outputs the below.

{0 0 0 } {0 0 0 } {0 0 0 } {0 0 0 }

{1 1 1 } {1 1 1 } {1 1 1 } {1 1 1 }

{2 2 2 } {2 2 2 } {2 2 2 } {2 2 2 }

{3 3 3 } {3 3 3 } {3 3 3 } {3 3 3 }

{4 4 4 } {4 4 4 } {4 4 4 } {4 4 4 }

I can't figure out how to output [1,2,3]. I know it has to do with scores[i][a][b] = i*1. So basically, how do I output [1,2,3] in a 3D array of 5 by 4 by 3?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: try `scores[i][a][b] = b+1;`

Comment: I am no professional when it comes to Java but as far as I can see, I don't see any bugs @Joe C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) 
{
  for (int a = 0; a < scores[i].length; a++) 
  {
         for (int b = 0; b < scores[i][a].length; b++) 
         {
            scores[i][a][b] = b+1;
         }
   }
}
```

you and a 3d array which goes 5 x 4 x 3 , you see in the code you start by looping through the 5 then the 4 then the 3. SInce you wanted 1,2,3  in each array by the time your looping in the 3 you just need to do whatever variable you have + 1 assuming you are starting at index 0;

Comment: Please edit your post and add explanation to your code. (E.g. what did you modify and why.)